# Why does `lspci --help | grep driver` fail?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, io-redirection, stderr

`lspci --help | grep driver` fails for some reason, it simply prints out the output instead of getting filtered by grep.

If I run `lspci --help | grep driver` I get:

```
lspci: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: lspci [<switches>]

Basic display modes:
-mm             Produce machine-readable output (single -m for an obsolete format)
-t              Show bus tree

Display options:
-v              Be verbose (-vv or -vvv for higher verbosity)
-k              Show kernel drivers handling each device
-x              Show hex-dump of the standard part of the config space
-xxx            Show hex-dump of the whole config space (dangerous; root only)
-xxxx           Show hex-dump of the 4096-byte extended config space (root only)
-b              Bus-centric view (addresses and IRQ's as seen by the bus)
-D              Always show domain numbers
-P              Display bridge path in addition to bus and device number
-PP             Display bus path in addition to bus and device number

Resolving of device ID's to names:
-n              Show numeric ID's
-nn             Show both textual and numeric ID's (names & numbers)
-q              Query the PCI ID database for unknown ID's via DNS
-qq             As above, but re-query locally cached entries
-Q              Query the PCI ID database for all ID's via DNS

Selection of devices:
-s [[[[<domain>]:]<bus>]:][<slot>][.[<func>]]   Show only devices in selected slots
-d [<vendor>]:[<device>][:<class>]              Show only devices with specified ID's

Other options:
-i <file>       Use specified ID database instead of /usr/share/hwdata/pci.ids
-p <file>       Look up kernel modules in a given file instead of default modules.pcimap
-M              Enable `bus mapping' mode (dangerous; root only)

PCI access options:
-A <method>     Use the specified PCI access method (see `-A help' for a list)
-O <par>=<val>  Set PCI access parameter (see `-O help' for a list)
-G              Enable PCI access debugging
-H <mode>       Use direct hardware access (<mode> = 1 or 2)
-F <file>       Read PCI configuration dump from a given file
```

instead of the output getting passed to `grep`.

I have tried it both in `zsh` and `bash` and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Many commands write their error message to [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) (2) and not to stdout (1). Replace `|` with `2>&1 |` to redirect stderr to stdout.

Comment: As you can see from the error output, `lspci` does not offer an option named `--help`. If you run it with any nonsense option, for instance `lspci -j`, it just writes some explanatory text to stderr. That's why you see this output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message itself *tells* you why it fails:

```
lspci: invalid option -- '-'
```

`--help` is not a valid option (neither is anything else starting with `--`). Thus, you get a usage message written as *diagnostic* content, and POSIX specifies that diagnostic contents belong on stderr (where it bypasses pipelines -- as is generally desirable, to ensure that diagnostic logs get to the human operator rather than being consumed by a pipeline).

Answer (score 1):

<s>Apperantely lsusb, [lspci and similar commands output their --help content to the stderr instead of the stdout](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/pciutils/pciutils.git/tree/setpci.c#n423) like most commands do.</s>

Some utils like lsusb and [lspci do not have a --help option, intead they print out their help string whenever they are used incorrectly](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/pciutils/pciutils.git/tree/lspci.c#n1193) (the help string is considered an error message in this case, this is why it gets outputted to the `stderr` instead of the `stout`)

To work around this I made the command fail on purpose with a random string argument of my choice (I used "a") and redirected the stderr to the stdout like this:

```
lspci a 2>&1 | grep driver
```

Thanks to [Charles Duffy's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77003958/16038645), [dschulz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212380/dschulz)
comment and [Fravadona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3387716/fravadona) comment for the clarifications and explanations.

Comment: There's no such `--help` option in `lspci`. Furthermore, `lspci` doesn't support any of the long '--' options you'd typically see in gnu userland.

Comment: @dschulz, heh, just so. Adding an answer to that effect.

Comment: It seams like you can use whatever `!/-.+/` string as argument for getting the help message without the `invalid option` line: for e.g. `lspci x`, lspci `-`, `lspci help`. It still errputs it though

Comment: @dschulz Indeed you are right, I was looking at the source of setpci, not lspci here:  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/pciutils/pciutils.git/tree/setpci.c#n469, also looking at the lspci source it seems infact there is not a "--help" option, it simply prints out the help string when it is used incorrectly https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/pciutils/pciutils.git/tree/lspci.c#n1193